# What's the difference between a list and a group on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

What is the difference between these two features also why can't I create a group "Military"...?

I did a couple quick Google searches, I couldn't really find a place that explained those two features in much depth.

Another thing if anyone knows where there is a guide or cheat sheet to Facebook's privacy settings/features could you please share.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The Difference Between Groups and Lists on Facebook:](http://www.micklerandassociates.com/whats-the-difference-between-groups-and-lists-on-facebook/)

> Conceptually, both of these features are similar. Both give you the
>   ability to create filters and add people to them. Example: you could
>   create a List called *Family*. You could then add your family members
>   you’ve friended. However, that’s about where their similarities end.
>
> **Groups** are a way of creating filters for viewing your wall. Say
>   that you created another group called *Work Colleagues*, and added
>   people to it. When viewing your Wall, you could then select the *Work
>   Colleagues* group to only see their posts. Groups are also shared with
>   your Friends – they, too, can see these filtered posts in this way.
>   Groups, though, do have a security setting:
>
> - **Open.** Everyone can see the members of this Group and read its
>     contents.
> - **Closed.** Members are public but the content is private.
> - **Secret.** Members and content is private.
>
> And Groups have customizations. You can add a specific picture to
>   represent the Group, and, you can select which members are admins to
>   the Group. You can also set up an SMTP (email) for the group so that
>   stuff emailed to the custom address will automatically post to its own
>   wall. In these ways, Groups almost look like Pages except you can’t
>   have those security settings.
>
> **Lists** are a bit different. Using a List, you can also create an
>   object you can add people to. As a matter of fact, this interface for
>   adding people to a List is much more sophisticated than the one for
>   Groups. But it’s not used as a filter against your Wall. Instead, it’s
>   used for security settings on your posts and for your Trust Settings.
>
> Example: if you were to create a List called *Circle of Trust* and add
>   people you really, really trust to it, you could then select that List
>   when you write a status update by selecting the Lock, hit Customize;
>   then select Specific People; then start typing the name of your List –
>   like, *Circle of Trust*. Only these people could then see your update.
>
> You can also tie Lists to Facebook’s Privacy Settings. In the
>   upper-right hand Account drop-down, select Privacy Settings, select
>   Custom, then Customize Settings. On the Things I Share List, you can
>   then follow similar instructions as above to restrict these specific
>   items to your List.
>
> It’s also noteworthy to mention that when you create a Group and add
>   people to it, that fact is broadcasted to your wall… even if you flag
>   the group as Secret, which seems kinda counter-intuitive. No such
>   notification happens when you create Lists or add people to Lists.
>
> **Conclusion:** Too bad that Facebook didn’t see it fit to combine
>   these options because they seem really similar to me, too, and the
>   word ‘Groups’ also describes mailing lists in Facebook, so it adds
>   just another layer of conceptual complexity. But there it is.

As for the Privacy Settings, check the following pages out:

- [Facebook Privacy: 10 Settings Every User Needs to Know](http://mashable.com/2011/02/07/facebook-privacy-guide/)
- [Facebook Help Center: Privacy](http://www.facebook.com/help/?page=419)

Comment: Thank you, also any reason I cannot create a group "Military"...?

Comment: @johnthexiii: You're welcome. I just guess that it may be a _reserved_ word, but I'm not sure.